# Child object with two parents - will child still exist if if I delete one parent?

Tags: relationships

I have doubt in the Parent-child relationship .Suppose I have scenario where an object is in a relationship with two parent objects. In that relationship if I delete one parent object, will the child object stll exist in the remaining relationship or will it be deleted?

Could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 6):

If child record has two lookup (two parents) then if anyone of them is deleted, child will **not be** deleted.

However, in case of Junction Object where one child has two Master detail relationship (two Parents), even one of them is deleted then **Child will be deletd**. [Check this post on how junction object works in Salesforce ?](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/deep-drive-in-junction-object-create-many-to-many-relationship-in-salesforce/)

Answer (score 0):

Few important points (usually interview  type Questions of salesforce ):

One Object can have only two Master-Detail relationships.
If we delete record A (First Master detail relationship is always primary)  – then child record c will be deleted.
If we delete record B then in this case also child record C will be deleted.
If we delete record c then only C will be deleted , master record will not be deleted.
If child C has two Master record A and B, Where A is primary relation then Child record C will inherit the look and feel of Parent object A.

Lookup relationship does not auto-delete any record when the parent or child is deleted.